# Calculating Pearson correlation not outputting correctly

Tags: python, pandas, pearson-correlation

I want to calculate correlation coeffecient between instruments, my database table is as follow:

```
"instrument"    "openprice_bid"
"CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP" "5249.16"
"KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP"    "5283.36"
"CS.D.SONY.TODAY.IP"    "5285.70"
"CS.D.FACEBOOK.TODAY.IP"    "5295.07"
"CS.D.BRENTCRUDE.TODAY.IP"  "5272.45"
"KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP"    "5270.39"
"CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP" "5264.01"
"CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP" "5275.67"
"CS.D.TESLA.TODAY.IP"   "5270.90"
"CS.D.SONY.TODAY.IP"    "5329.63"
```

I have managed to load the data into a dataframe using this code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT instrument,openprice_bid FROM %s;" % 'market_data_historic', engine)
d=df.corr
print(d)
```

This generates this output instead of an actual correlation matrix, what am I doing wrong??:

```
 KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP        1851.00
1458495        KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP        1851.00
1458496        KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP        1846.00
1458497        KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP        1849.00
1458498        KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP        1854.00
1458499        KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP        1855.00
1458500        KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP        1846.00
1458501        KA.D.CHNPLN.MAR.IP        1848.00
```

Comment: Are you trying to check the correlation of single array to what?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Can you print the data frame and check whether it has headers or it is in the wrong format. If it is fine please try to convert strings in instrument column to numbers.

Comment: You need to calculate it so that you first generate cols for each instrument. If you have timestamp use that as index then that one should work.

Comment: I have a timestamp column, can I do this?  df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT timestamp,instrument,openprice_bid FROM %s;" % 'market_data_historic', index_col='timestamp',engine)